# Второй Controller в Spring не находит .html

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Первый контроллер работает корректно,

```
@Controller
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MainController {
 @RequestMapping("/profile")
    private String g(){
        return "Profile.html";
    }
}
```

Второй:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/gallery")
public class GContoller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/month")
    String ffff() {
        return "monthGallery.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    String test() {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

Страница `localhost:8080/gallery/test` открывается и выводится test, однако `localhost:8080/gallery/month` выводит ошибку 404. Очевидно, что второй контроллер не может найти файл monthGallery.html, но как указать ему это? Все html файлы находятся в `/webapp`.

Структура проекта

`/java
     /ru.example.xxx
/webapp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно добавить `spring.view.prefix=/` в `application.properties`